# How to create a class or method for multiple instance of webview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview

I have 3 fragments with their 3 layouts in tablayout. All three layout have their individual webview, swipeRefreshLayout and a progress bar. Currently I copy paste the same code in all three fragments . I want to make a class or a single method such that the changes i make in it will reflect on all three webview setting in the fragment

Below is my fragment, I just copy and paste the code below in all three fragments  & only change the url.

```
public class Yahoo extends Fragment {


    final String url = "http://www.yahoo.com/";
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar1;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout1;


    public Yahoo() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab13, container, false);


    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.website_detail_1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

                progressBar1.setProgress(progress);

                if (progress == 100) {

                    progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    if (mSwipeRefreshLayout1.isRefreshing()) {
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                } else {
                    progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }


        });


        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        });

        webView.loadUrl(url);


        mSwipeRefreshLayout1 = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe1);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });

        webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Log.d("Yahoo webview", "destroy");
        if (webView != null) {
            webView.removeAllViews();
            webView.destroy();
        }

        webView = null;
    }

}
```

Could you help me out as how to create a class and and handle objects like webview , progress bar & swipeRefreshLayout such that I dont have to duplicate the same code in all three fragments ?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can suggest is that you create a single Fragment class, then create 3 instances of it using different urls.

So you will have **one** fragment class and **one** layout for it. And then you just **instantiate them with different urls** (if url is the only difference between them)

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you for the tips.